# GraphQL - Are "Federations" a Vanilla Graphql thing or an Apollo thing?

Tags: graphql, schema, apollo, apollo-federation

I'm having a hard time differentiating from what's vanilla GraphQL and what's **Apollo**.

I'm trying to understand schema stitching and see that using **Fragments** and **Federation** are two different ways to do this.

Found this enlightening 
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-stitching/

Do I have to buy-in to **Apollo** to use **Federations**?

Answer (score 2):

On the [graphql spec](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/) there is no mention of Federations. Federations are only a part of apollo.